# Сan a subset of features perform better than the base set?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have a random forest model which is trained on 100 features for example. After doing feature selection using the same model, let's say I now have 40 features and I name the subset of features as `basic feature set`.

Now my question is that, will my model perform better if choose few features from the `basic feature set` or is it already the best set by default?

Answer (score 1):

If by 'work better' you mean 'having less generalization error', then yes it is possible.

Consider the extreme case that we have 100 features, but only 1 of them is truly causally relevant to the target and the rest are just noise/random numbers.

If we feed all 100 features into a model, it will spend a lot of (useless) effort trying to relate the 99 'features' with target. If we are lucky, this means a waste of time and model capacity; worse case is the model does find some seemingly-true relationships after trying hard enough.

In this case a simple model with the 1 feature can beat them all.

This is what we call fitting noise, and is commonly seen in predicting complex system where a lot of data are available, e.g. stock market and global economy.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of your model after feature selection depends on various factors. The basic feature set you have after feature selection is not necessarily the best set by default. It is the set of features that the feature selection method has determined to be the most important or relevant for your model.

However, it is possible that a subset of these features could yield a better performing model. This could be due to interactions between features, redundancy in the information provided by some features, or simply because the feature selection method was not able to perfectly identify the optimal feature set.

Therefore, it is always a good idea to experiment with different subsets of features and evaluate the performance of your model. This can be done through methods such as cross-validation, where you train your model on a portion of your data and test it on a separate portion to evaluate its performance.

Remember, the goal is to find a balance between model complexity (more features) and model performance. Adding more features can make your model more complex and may lead to overfitting, where your model performs well on the training data but poorly on new, unseen data. On the other hand, removing too many features may oversimplify your model and cause underfitting, where your model does not perform well even on the training data.